# $f(X)$ is differentiable at $x=a$ but it is discontinuous

Tags: continuity

I have defined a function such that:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}mx,&(x\le a),
\\ mx+c,&(x>a).\end{cases}$$

Here according to the derivative definition :

$f '(a) = \lim_{x\to a} [f (x) - f (a) ]/ [x - a] $

we can show that this limit exits by taking the LHS and RHS limits , and showing that they are equal. Since the gradient is the same I think it is trivial .

Can anyone please explain ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please show that the limit exists.

Comment: Look carefully at how you have defined $f(a)$ and check your assertion that the limits on each side exist.

Comment: Guessing where things went wrong. "Since the gradient is the same I think it is trivial": What's  trivial is that $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=m$. That does _not_ imply that $f'(a)$ exists - that's not the limit in the definition of $f'(a)$.

Comment: Thankyou so much @David C. Ullrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand limit does not exist. Remember, $f(a) = ma$, **not** $ma + c$, even when you're finding the right hand limit.

Comment: Thank you so much